# Angular 14 stuck on, Generating browser application bundles (phase: building) at the time of build

Tags: angular

Terminal is keep showing Generating browser application bundles (phase: building) when trying to build.

[image]

Angular Version : **14.2.0**

Could anyone suggest workaround/solution to overcome from this.

Thanks

Comment: --clearcache & try again

Comment: tried, still facing the same.