# Angular 15 is stuck on Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm building an angular app using `npm start` but it is stuck on

```
Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...
```

I've tried many solutions like clearing npm cache using

```
npm cache clean --force
```

I've also tried all solutions suggested on previously asked questions related to the same issue happening on [angular 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65537399/angular-11-stuck-on-generating-browser-application-bundles-phase-building) and [angular 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76779360/angular-14-stuck-on-generating-browser-application-bundles-phase-building-at) but nothing worked for me.

Here are the versions of Angular and node installed on my device:

```
Angular CLI: 15.1.5
Node: 18.19.0
Package Manager: npm 10.2.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 15.1.4
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1501.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.1.5
@angular-devkit/core            15.1.5
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.1.5
@angular/cli                    15.1.5
@schematics/angular             15.1.5
rxjs                            7.5.7
typescript                      4.8.4
```

Comment: Did you try to clear or disable angular cache? do you see different behavier for ng serve and ng build for the different configurations?

Comment: I've tried but there is no difference @ThomasRenger